# How do I find out the complexity needed for a Unix password

Tags: unix, passwd

My Unix password has timed out, and I need to enter a new one, so I get this bit as soon as I login:

```
Current Password:####  
New Password:
```

but anything I type is too simple (apparently), even `1y4y5re987wnf`

Is there something I can type to find out the rules around the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask your system administrator: it may be that `1y4y5re987wnf` is rejected because it does not contain any special characters or no capitalized letters. You can also find more information about your required password in the file `/etc/default/passwd`.

Comment: thanks, i thought that might be the case, but i wondered. thanks very much for confirming.

Comment: What if you _are_ the system administrator? (I'm just running Ubuntu on a machine, and I'm getting that error message) `/etc/default/passwd` does not exist on my system.

Comment: @IQAndreas: You can invoke `passwd` with `sudo`. That way it won't reject passwords it considers unsafe. https://xkcd.com/149/.

Comment: @SiyuanRen Brilliant, that fixed it! (Though I'm still curious what the password requirements are by default for ordinary users)

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you to need at least one capital letter, at least one lower case letter, at least one digit, preferably at least one punctuation or control character, and at least 8 characters in total.  However, without knowing a lot more about which version of Unix (Linux, etc) you are using, no-one can be more precise than that.  Different systems will impose different rules.  Different systems will likely impose different upper limits on the length of a password.